# How to urlencode url params with a curl POST but not urlencode the body data?

Tags: shell, curl

When making a curl POST call with something like `... | curl -XPOST --data @- https://example.com/` can I *also* url-encode some url params on the command line (using curl itself, not bash funcs) without having to encode them myself and put them in the url argument to curl?

**So I want the POST Body *to not be* urlencoded, but the url params *to be* url encoded within the same curl command.**

So for example:

```
echo '{"username":"a","password": [1,2]}' | curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST -d@- --data-urlencode "filter=." http://localhost:8080
```

Doesn't seem to do what I want, and I have postfix my `https://localhost:8080/` url with `?filter...` which I would rather avoid for cases when the param needs a lot of encoding.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `--data-urlencode` option:

```
... | curl -s -X POST --data @- --data-urlencode "filter=ab&123" <url>
```

As per `man curl`:

> `--data-urlencode <data>`
>   (HTTP) This posts data, similar to the other `-d`, `--data` options with the exception that this performs URL-encoding.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to encode the data, only some url params. So I want both behaviors at once

Comment: I think that is the inverse of what I am after, edited my question some.  JSON will be coming over stdin, and then I don't want to have escape the url params myself.

Comment: `--data-urlencode` takes care of encoding your data. Test with these 2 options: `--data-urlencode "filter=ab&123"` and then `--data "filter=ab&123"` and you will note difference. `ab&123` is correctly encoded as `filter=ab%26123` only when you use  `-data-urlencode` but not when you use `--data`

Comment: I get the difference between data and data-urlencode in that respect, but is there a anyway to encode url params but not encode post data?

Comment: See my updated command. `--data @-` doesn't encode your POST body and `--data-urlencode "filter=ab&123"` encodes whatever additional data you want to encode.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me.... I believe that matches what is in my question more or less.  Have you confirmed the behavior or is that the way you expect to work based on the man pages?

Comment: I never post any answer without verifying myself. It might be some misunderstanding between requirement and solution. Here is output of what I am seeing: https://pastebin.com/8q0GmPe4 Note difference of `--data` and `--data-urlencode` in output from URL where I am just dumping all the input using `var_dump( file_get_contents('php://input') );`

Comment: "I never post any answer without verifying myself" I apologize - I should expect as much from such a high rep user - just trying to wrap my head around what I'm see and wanted to be sure - I should have worded that more carefully. I greatly appreciate this help!

Comment: So going off your pastebin, I think what I would be hoping to see would be `'POST /post.php?filter=.user%23name HTTP/1.1` and then the JSON is the post body.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused because of how --data-urlencode behaves with a GET? (with the `-G` option), something like `curl --data-urlencode 'filter=.' -G http://localhost:8080 -vvv` makes `GET /?filter=. HTTP/1.1`

Comment: But using `-G` option will also try to convert your POST body as query string that you definitely don't want.

Comment: So sounds like what I want would be a feature request to curl.